# COM+ component calling other COM+ components - “Cannot load type"

Tags: vb.net, com, com-interop, vb6-migration, com+

I have a two .NET assemblies which are registered as COM+ components and I'm testing them from a regular console application test harness;

```
Dim objFirst As New MyFirstComponent() 'COM+ initialisation
Dim RC As Boolean = objFirst.GetValue()
The method call is executed successfully. This is the definition of 
MyFirstComponent;

<ProgId("MyFirstComponent")> _
<Guid("...")> _
<ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)> _
<Transaction(TransactionOption.Supported)> _
 Public Class MyFirstComponent
  Inherits ServicedComponent
  Implements IMyFirstComponent
 Public Function GetValue() As Boolean Implements 
  IMyFirstComponent.GetValue
   Dim objSecond As New MySecondComponent() 'COM+ initialisation
   Dim RC As Boolean = objSecond.GetValue()
  Return RC
End Function
End Class
```

At the point where MySecondComponent is initialised, I get a
   RemotingException with the following message;

> "Cannot load type 'MySecondComponent', ..., Version=...,
>   Culture=neutral, 
>       PublicKeyToken=...'

All assemblies are strongly named too. I cannot work out why I can 
   successfully fire a method call to the first component, but when it tries 
   to subsequently load up the second component itself, it can't resolve the 
   type.

As a sidenote, if I run the code from the body of "`GetValue()`" in my test 
   harness, it executes as expected. The problem seems to only crop up once 
   things have moved into the realm of COM+ components calling other COM+ 
   components.